# Alinear el contenido de sus hijos en grid

Tags: css, grid

He estado intentando centrar el contenido de un contenedor grid (vaya la redundancia) sin embargo no lo he logrado. Lo que intento es que, tengo una columna con filas, las cuales son partidas por fracciones `(1/7 para la primera fila, y 7/13 para la siguiente)`.

Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema radica cuando, el contenido de estas, queda desalineada, es decir, que una queda muy arriba y la otra muy abajo. (La parte de Academy y Skills). Muestro una imagen:
[image: Imagen del grid]

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}


.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.academy {
  grid-column: 1/7;
}

.skills {
  grid-column: 7/13;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
        <div class="grid">
          <div class="academy">
            <h2 class="border text">Academy</h2>
            <div class="items">
              <article class="item">
                <h3 class="">Universidad Veracruzana</h3>
                <span>Agost 2015 - Febrero 2021</span>
                <ul>
                  <li>Licenciado en Tecnologias Computacionales</li>
                </ul>
              </article>
              <article class="item">
                <h3 class="">Platzi</h3>
                <span>Marzo 2020 - Actualidad</span>
                <ul>
                  <li>Escuela de Desarrolo Web</li>
                </ul>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="skills">
            <h2 class="border text">Skills</h2>
            <div class="items">
              <article class="item">
                <ul>
                  <li>Creativo</li>
                </ul>
              </article>
              <article class="item">
                <ul>
                  <li>Creativo</li>
                </ul>
              </article>
              <article class="item">
                <ul>
                  <li>Creativo</li>
                </ul>
              </article>
              <article class="item">
                <ul>
                  <li>Creativo</li>
                </ul>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Creo que es porque `.skills` tiene una altura menor que el otro div y la está centrando verticalmente. Creo que se soluciona cambiando esta parte: `align-items: start;`

Comment: Tienes razón. La duda que tengo es ¿Cómo logro que ambas tengan la misma altura (y anchura). Para evitar que se muestren así :(

Comment: ¿Probaste cambiando eso que dije? Edité el comentario y quizás no llegaste a leer esa parte.

Comment: Lo intente pero, me sigue mostrando igual.

Comment: Recién probé cambiándolo en el navegador con la opción de ejecutar y queda alineado. Quizás no entendí bien la pregunta. ¿Lo que buscás es que el encabezado "Academy" quede a la misma altura que "Skills"? Si es eso se soluciona cambiando `align-items: center` por `align-items: start` en `.grid`. Si no se soluciona con eso probablemente haya algún conflicto con otra regla que no figura en el código que compartiste.

Comment: Si, era eso. Gracias por responder. Crea la respuesta para que de por cerrada mi pregunta, de favor. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Habría que cambiar `align-items: center;` por `align-items: start;` en `.grid` para que no centre el contenido verticalmente.